# Why does my Ruby string show the escape character backslash ('\') twice?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I'm using `\.br\` as delimiter:

```
[10, 20, 30].join('\.br\\')
```

expected result:

```
"10\.br\20\.br\30"
```

what is actually returned:

```
"10\\.br\\20\\.br\\30"
```

I added escape for the backslash, how could I get the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll find that the backslashes are not in fact doubled in the string.
To check, instead of printing it using [`p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p) (which uses [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-inspect)) just print it using [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts).

When the string is `inspect`ed it uses double-quotes, and tries to produce a version of the string that you can copy and paste in to Ruby to get the same string - so it needs to double up the backslash characters.

Comment: i still don't understand. if I use puts, it's good. how exactly could i solve my problem?

Comment: @seanan - The point is that you don't have a problem. Your string is exactly how you would expect it, it is irb that displays it in that weird way - as soon as you try to use that string in the application you will see it is normal.

Comment: You don't have a problem. The backslashes are not doubled in your string. They're doubled in the printed output which is generated for your string. Print the number of characters instead, to verify that.

Comment: thanks. is this a ruby thing, or there's some common pattern here?

Comment: @seanan it's an [irb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html) thing - irb uses `inspect` for output and therefore escapes strings.